# Security in collaborative software (collaboration groups)

Tags: security, symfony, architecture

Lets say i have objects A, B, C, D, E, F, collaborator groups C1, C2, users C1U1 (admin), C1U2 (user), C2U1 (admin), C2U2 (user).

A, C, E belongs to group C1. 
B, D, F belongs to group C2.

Thus only members of correpsonding group can view their respective objects. Also any object created ends up in group to which its creator (user) belongs.

Admin can create and edit every entity, user can only create entities and only edit his entities.

And ofcourse each user (admin or regular user) as said before can view only entities that belong to his group.

In my particular task there are number of type of entities (static)  and number of types of users (static). There will be multiple collaboration groups (dynamic) where users will create some entities. Some of the users will have ability only to view entities (to which they are entitiled to view due to being member of correspodning collaboration group), create and edit. Some of them will have ability to edit entities of other users (but only ceratin types of entities). Essentialy its a little bit like JIRA.

That said, my question is quite simple: what pattern helps organising this stuff? I believe this is a common problem, thus it must have common name.

I know there is a blunt way to create this. Im using symfony 2 and it have both RBAC and ACL, but not RBACL afaik. RBAC will help me with user types (i use UserGroups and i create roles like ROLE_EDIT_ENTITYTYPE1), checks for ownership are performed with ACL.

But how do i implement those collaboration groups?

Im sorry if my explanation sounds vague or just stupid or anything else, i would like to hear anything about subject. I got a feeling that i'm missing something here.

PS: Not sure about "security" tag, if its related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case the just Role Hierachy is not suffiecient enough. What you need is complete ACL:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

You can create the ACL right in a Listener when Entities are saved and then grant the access for all the group members.

You can also work with different ACL Masks, in order to control which user can EDIT entities and which users can only view them:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html

Sorry for mainly linking to the default documentation, but I think this basically covers everything you need.